# How to rename files in multiple folders without renaming the directories?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a bunch of directories (e.g., `drawable-hdmi`, `drawable-en-hdmi`, `drawable-en-xhdmi`) and so on for different resolutions and localisations. each of them contain just one file with a random name. 
How can I rename those files with a command to to `new_begingn.9.png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` with `mv`:

```
find drawable-hdmi drawable-en-hdmi drawable-en-xhdmi -type f -exec mv {} new_begingn.9.png \;
```

If all the folders are named `drawable-<something>`, you can do:

```
find drawable-* -type f -exec mv {} new_begingn.9.png \;
```